# How to search for numbers in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I've just begun to study Python. I have matrix (stored in a file called `linhas.txt`, with 15 columns and 30.000 rows).

How can I select particular rows which 10 numbers selected?

I try this code, but not work:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = [4,6,8,9,10,12,13,14,22,24]

matrix = (np.loadtxt("linhas.txt", usecols=()))

for numbers in matrix:
    print(matrix)
```

Result was:

```
 ...,
 [  7.   9.  10. ...,  23.  24.  25.]
 [  8.   9.  10. ...,  23.  24.  25.]
 [  9.  10.  11. ...,  23.  24.  25.]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

A exemple the first rows:

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 11 14 15 22 24 25

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 11 18 19 20 22 25

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 12 13 15 16 17 18

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 12 15 19 20 22 24

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 12 18 19 20 24 25

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 12 18 19 21 24 25

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 13 15 18 20 21 24

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 13 15 18 21 22 23

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 13 15 18 21 22 25

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 13 15 19 21 22 24

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 13 17 19 20 21 25

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 10 13 17 19 20 22 23

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 11 13 14 15 16 17 19

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 09 11 15 17 18 21 22 24

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 10 11 12 13 14 19 20 24

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 10 11 12 13 14 19 20 25

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 10 11 12 13 14 20 22 23

01 02 03 04 05 07 08 10 11 12 13 15 19 20 23

Comment: Can you post your `linhas.txt`, please?

Comment: Which rows are you trying to select? Are the integers in `numbers` supposed to be indexes of rows in your matrix, or are they integers that you want to search each row for?

Comment: The rows are intergers numbers.

Comment: yes, they are integers that i want to search each row in matrix.